# Handling pressed event in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-dialog, kotlin-coroutines

I have RecyclerView with simple items. I want to handle onPress event. If user press and hold finger on item for 2 seconds, it should remove it. But I don't know how to handle delay. I've used CoroutineScope to delay callback call from AlertDialog, but this caused error.

Solution:

```
vh.root.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
     if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          launch {
              delay(2000)
              onChosen(true, item.vehicleId, i, this@dialogCustomView)
          }
      }
      true
}
```

Error: `android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@a1d8d91[Item1] that was originally added here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe `setOnLongClickListener` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don 't know if this is exactly what you want, but here' s what I usually do (though I use on click most of the time:

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    val myItems = mutableListOf<Item>()

    ....

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.update(myItems[position], position)
    }

    fun itemTouched(position: Int) {
        myItems.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : Recyclerview.Viewholder(view) {
        var mPosition = -1
        var mLastTouch: Long = 0

        init {
            view.SetOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mLastTouch = System.currentTimeMillis()

            }else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTouch > 2000) {
                    this@MyAdapter.itemTouched(mPosition)
                }
                mLastTouch = 0
            }
        }
    }
            }
        }

        fun update(item: Item, position: Int) {
            mPosition = position
            //do updates from item
        }
    }
}
```